# when delete data from recycler view change check item to uncheck in recycler view

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, checkbox, android-recyclerview

When i check item from recyclerview one i can add item in recyclerview second which is on same activity.
When i delete item from second recyclerview through image i want to clear selected checkbox as unselected
in recyclerview first one.In Advance Thanks!!

---

****ListdataAdapter.java****

```
      @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ListdataAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       final ListModel model = listData.get(position);

               holder.tvNumber.setText(model.getId());
               holder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
               holder.cbAction.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                     if(isChecked){
                  addcheckvalue.add(new CheckedValueModel(model.getId(),model.getName()));
                  itemCheckListner.onClicked(addcheckvalue);
               }else{

               Toast.makeText(context,"Item Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    
       });

   }
```

****CheckedListAdapter****

```
   @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(CheckedListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       final CheckedValueModel model = checkedList.get(position);

          holder.tvNumber.setText(model.getId());
          holder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
         holder.crossImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckedValueModel item = checkedList.get(position);
            checkedList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,checkedList.size());
            Toast.makeText(context,"Removed : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

****interface ItemCheckListner****

```
  public interface ItemCheckListner{
   void onClicked(List<CheckedValueModel>list);
```

}

****MainActivity****

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ItemCheckListner {

```
RecyclerView rvDataList;
ListdataAdapter listdataAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
List<ListModel> dataList;

ArrayList<CheckedValueModel> checkedList;
RecyclerView rvCheckedList;
CheckedListAdapter checkedListAdapter;
CheckedValueModel checkedValueModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    checkedList = new ArrayList<>();

    rvDataList = findViewById(R.id.rvDataList);
    rvCheckedList = findViewById(R.id.rvCheckedList);

    listdataAdapter = new ListdataAdapter(dataList, this, this::onClicked);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvDataList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rvDataList.setAdapter(listdataAdapter);
    listdataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    datalist();

    Log.d("checklist_size", "" + checkedList.size());

 //   checkedList.add(checkedValueModel);
    checkedListAdapter = new CheckedListAdapter(checkedList, this);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvCheckedList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rvCheckedList.setAdapter(checkedListAdapter);
    checkedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void datalist() {
    dataList.add(new ListModel("1", "Piyush"));
    dataList.add(new ListModel("2", "Raj"));
    dataList.add(new ListModel("3", "Ravi"));
    dataList.add(new ListModel("4", "Kapil"));
}



@Override
public void onClicked(List<CheckedValueModel>list) {

    checkedList=(ArrayList<CheckedValueModel>)list;
    checkedListAdapter.updateData(checkedList);
    //Toast.makeText(this, data.getId() + data.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

****CheckedValueModel && ListModel ****

**

### Both model are same.

**

public class CheckedValueModel {

```
String id;
String name;

public CheckedValueModel(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: Any Solution Gabriele Mariotti??

Comment: same code i want to use in kotlin too is it possible Thanks in advance and replay soon if possible.